# I want to send data from Lua to C#

Tags: c#, lua, udp

This is Lua code. I want to send XXPos, YYPos, ZZPos. But In unity3d, It receive XXPos only.

```
  socket = require("socket")
  print(socket._VERSION)

  function dataListener:post( t )

    local XPos = ship.rb:getPosition():x()
    local YPos = ship.rb:getPosition():y()
    local ZPos = ship.rb:getPosition():z()
    local XXPos = math.floor( XPos * 1000 + 0.5 ) / 1000
    local YYPos = math.floor( YPos * 1000 + 0.5 ) / 1000
    local ZZPos = math.floor( ZPos * 1000 + 0.5 ) / 1000

    udp=socket.udp();
    udp:setpeername("127.0.0.1",8051)
    udp:send(XXPos, " ", YYPos, " ", ZZPos);
  end
```

When I change Lua code like this,

```
--udp:send(XXPos, " ", YYPos, " ", ZZPos)
  udp:send(string.format("%d; %d; %d",XXPos,YYPos,ZZPos))
```

The data is received correctly. But this result has 1 digit like 3; 5; 2.

How do I change this Lua code?

Comment: What do you mean by "this result has 1 digit like 3; 5; 2."? Besides that, it seems udp:send() only takes one argument, so you have to assemble the string. string.format is the way to go.

Comment: I want a rainbow unicorn.

Comment: What do you expected to be?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen  XXPos result is 0.xxx . So, I want 0.xxx; x.xxx; x.xxx

Comment: @JimanAn Look at my answer. That's probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I think @Programmer is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
udp:send(string.format("%d; %d; %d",XXPos,YYPos,ZZPos))
```

should be  `udp:send(string.format("%f; %f; %f",XXPos,YYPos,ZZPos))`

Notice the `%f`. That means float.